# WiFi clips out after 4.19.6 kernel

Tags: wireless, kernel, 18.10

WiFi used to work fine on 4.19.1 but after upgrading my kernel it stops working after a while. I've tried a few things that do not work:

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service networking restart
```

None of them do the trick. I do have some logs from the last time it stopped but I can't turn them into an actionable item. Anybody have a tip?

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2018-12-03 19:51:48 EST. --
Jan 02 21:20:01 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <info>  [1546482001.2483] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 02 21:20:01 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <info>  [1546482001.2497] device (wlo1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 02 21:20:01 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <info>  [1546482001.2501] device (wlo1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 02 21:20:01 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <info>  [1546482001.2506] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 02 21:20:01 envy dhclient[2054]: bound to 192.168.86.41 -- renewal in 33503 seconds.
Jan 02 21:20:01 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <info>  [1546482001.2625] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan 02 21:20:01 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <info>  [1546482001.2627] policy: set 'owlbear' (wlo1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jan 02 21:20:01 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <info>  [1546482001.2635] device (wlo1): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 02 21:20:01 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <info>  [1546482001.2647] manager: startup complete
Jan 02 21:20:01 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <info>  [1546482001.3803] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL

---> GOES DOWN HERE <-----------

Jan 02 22:10:14 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <warn>  [1546485014.2700] sup-iface[0x56522e92b8e0,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Jan 02 22:10:14 envy NetworkManager[1296]: <info>  [1546485014.2842] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disabled
Jan 02 22:10:14 envy dhclient[2054]: receive_packet failed on wlo1: Network is down
```

Comment: I would be more worried about file corruption in the 4.19 kernel

Comment: same issue in 4.20 kernel, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Why not use supported kernel versions?

Comment: Supported kernel versions don't work with my laptop's touchscreen. That issue was fixed in 4.19.5. There were also some reported improvements for AMD GPU's in 4.20 that I wanted to review.